# ngx-quill error while aot building in angular 8

Tags: angular, typescript, quill, ngx-quill

I am using ngx-quill to add quill editor in my angular application.
Here is the configuration

`app.module.ts`

```
import { QuillModule } from 'ngx-quill';

@NgModule({
    imports:[
      QuillModule.forRoot()
    ]
})
```

This works fine when i compile my application in JIT and also in development mode.
But when I try build AOT

There is this error

```
ERROR in Error during template compile of 'AppModule'
  Function calls are not supported in decorators but 'QuillModule' was called.
```

How can I solve this error and build in AOT using quill module

Comment: I had to use the library to the old version to get rid of this error.

Comment: I had to disable ivy.